# Azure Storage Account Event subscription: Event not getting delivered to subscription

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, azure-storage-account

The requirement is when a file gets uploaded to a storage account container, a logic should be in force to encrypt the file and place it in another container and source file should not get affected. For this I setup an event subscription in storage account, which would publish event to an event grid system topic, in turn triggers an Azure function. Below is the screenshot of event subscription setup.
[image]

The issue is the event gets published to event grid system topic but not getting delivered to subscription. I set up diagnostic settings for the event grid system topic. Below is the error that I found in logs. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

*outcome=Forbidden,deliveryResponse=Forbidden, errorCode=Forbidden, HttpRequestMessage: httpVersion=1.1, HttpResponseMessage: HttpVersion=1.1, StatusCode=Forbidden(Forbidden), StatusDescription=Ip Forbidden, ConnectionInfo=defaultConnectionLimit=1024, reusePortSupported=True, reusePort=True,*

Answer (score 0):

To the Azure function app, add an inbound traffic rule under Networking option to allow traffic from Azure EventGrid